# blank page when deploying .net core project with react in an Azure App services

Tags: .net, reactjs, azure, asp.net-core-webapi

I developed a WEB api application. The problem is, when I deploy on staging or production slot azure app services a blank page is showed. My application works  as follows : 
Web API project in .net core produce data to consume in react front.

here is my csproj file :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
<SpaRoot>Front\</SpaRoot>
<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\** 
</DefaultItemExcludes>
   <UserSecretsId>14b3dfa4-fc53-4655-ba9e-e3589f2c620f</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
<None Include="wwwroot\Document\ProductService.xml" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" 
Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" 
Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="React.AspNet" Version="3.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />  
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project 
files list -->
<Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
<None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" 
'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
<!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
<Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
</Exec>
<Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build 
and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from 
https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
<Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This 
may take several minutes..." />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
<!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in 
production mode -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

<!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" 
Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind />
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

What is wrong in my deployment ? why I have a blank page in azure and not in localhost. either I launch in debug or directly after npm run build in localhost. Its works please help thanks you

Best regards.

Comment: how is the application being deployed? is it via Visual Studio ? Powershell? CLI ? if possible add details on how the app was deployed.

Comment: Yes I use the publish screen on visual studio. with release mode and runtime target :  portable. I am created github repository in few minutes.

Comment: here my repos => https://github.com/Eric75015/ProductReact

Comment: Please help....

Comment: i took a clone of your code and tried to run it locally and it errors out when it tries to connect to the product db . I am not sure if it is configured right. or for security purpose you have not committed the connection details. Also am not sure how you are handling the routing for the UI pages. when it runs in web server like IIS routing has be done so that the web server has a map of what to render for a given request. check this post https://medium.com/@to_pe/deploying-create-react-app-on-microsoft-azure-c0f6686a4321 if you have not done it already.

Comment: @Aravind, unfortunately his case is not related with mine. he's using static server behinf all this. I Use WEB API project hosting with kestrel server. but thanks for this post. And yes of course I hide the connection string and some config files from the repository sorry.